# SQL - subtract between two dates

Tags: sql, mysqli

I'm trying to find the number of days between two date columns.
I tried to use DATEDIFF but I got an error. What more should I do

Thanks,

Comment: post your code and error here for a start.

Comment: Post code, but before that, try again with 
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate. Maybe you have syntax errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct SQL syntax for your database?  Since you're using MySQL, you need to do a

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2015-06-05', '2015-08-05');
```

and the difference is always expressed in days.

On SQL Server you need to specify the unit e.g.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2015-06-05', '2015-08-05');
```